# Add page to certain div in bootstrap modal windows

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project that use bootstrap, in it I need to show modal windows that contain other html page I use the following code

```
<a class="menuItemManageContent" 
 href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/news/index/NEWS/0943ac5b-e556-49eb-acef-a112a56e3e7b/managePortlet.html"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-table_<%= request.getParameter("instanceId").toString() %>">Manage content</a>

<div id="modal-table_<%= request.getParameter("instanceId").toString() %>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header no-padding">
                <div class="table-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                        <span class="white">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    mange
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contentBody" class="modal-body no-padding">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

the code above work fine , it is showing the modal with my page in it the only part I need to put my content in contentBody so I still have the header for the modal as I design it, my question here is there is an easy way to do that with no javascript, can I tell the data-target to put the page in the contentBody div instead of the default modal content which is override my div.

Answer (score 0):

fine, i got it work I just move the header out of the content and that solve the issue, I will leave this question hopefully it help someone else